# Text in EditText cannot be showed normally

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-edittext

Text only shows when I click the buttons in action menu or  in navigation bar.
Here is my code

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "match_parent"
    android:orientation = "vertical"
    >
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">  
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height = "fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:background="#000"
                    android:id="@+id/Editor"


                    />

        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background = "#FFF"
    >
    <ListView 
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "match_parent"
        />
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
</FrameLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And this is part of my DrawerLayout

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                                              R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
                                              R.string.drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

I think drawing of drawer is coverd drawing of EditText. Is there a solution?

Comment: Okay, It's the problem of Material Theme. But I want to use the material theme, what should I do?